# javascript doesn't work with LI tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

hi i have this code

## html code

```
<ul>
<input type="button" onclick="appear()"/>
<li id="addQuestionChoices">roma</li>
</ul>
```

## css code

```
#addQuestionChoices{display:none;}
```

## javascript code

```
function appear()
{document.getElementById('addQuestionChoices').style.display="block";}
```

but when i press the button , nothing happend, is javascript doesn't work with LI tag ? or what ?
thank you for answering

Comment: Try putting the <li> tag inside a <ul> element.

Comment: what do you expect to happen?

Comment: i expect that roma will be appread after clicking the button

Comment: Are you sure you don't see any error in the javascript console?

Comment: Please validate your HTML before coming to StackOverflow. There are several tools for that. With the corrected HTML, your code works great, [see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/84SMM/).

Comment: @fgyukkeb  yes i am sure

Comment: @bazmegakap  i know i am new to html , so i asked , is it a bad thing i am not good in html ?

Comment: Valid HTML is very important for cross browser compatibility.  [Always validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: @WilliamKinaan You are new, and I have given you good advice. Do whatever you want with it :).

Comment: There is nothing wrong on not being good in html. You said you wrote the question quickly, that's the problem. Try to post a [Short, Self Contained, and Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the problem. Put more effort into writing your questions, and you might even find the solution yourself in the process. You have many valid answers here and none seem to solve the problem, so the problem might be somewhere else. A typo somewhere on your code, likely an ID. Who knows?

Comment: now it is works , i am really thank you , and sorry for losing your time, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad practice to embed JavaScript calls within HTML. It makes the code much more maintainable when the functionality, style and markup are kept seperate. Secondly your `<li>` element should be nested within either a pair of `<ul>` or `<ol>` tags.

I have written a jsFiddle example of how you could tackle this task:

http://jsfiddle.net/dLqja/1/

In this code I have created a 'click' listener, this is attached to your button via its id. Upon the button press it triggers an anonymous callback function which dynamically changes the display style of your 'li' element.

**Inclusion of jQuery**

Make the following is the first JavaScript that you include in your page.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This jQuery script is hosted by Google, which has its advantages such as (it's probably already cached in the clients browser from visiting a previous website using it).

Any JavaScript code which you write which uses the functionality of jQuery should be included after the above script.

## None jQuery Version...

You can achieve a similar result as the above by assigning an event listener to the button. This approach is preferable to using onclick="..." as sticks to the rule of seperating functionality from markup. If none of these answers work you should check your browsers console for error messages.
http://jsfiddle.net/SvufY/1/

Comment: thank you , i love your way of coding javascript , but that javacript where should be ? in my js files ?

Comment: yes, you need to include jQuery. I'll update my answer with an explanation of how to use this code.

Comment: The question is about JavaScript and you provide a solution requiring jQuery (see answer by @saluce).  Secondly, don't post your answer if it's incomplete... how am I or anyone else supposed to know you're still _"working on it"_?

Comment: See my answer for a non-jQuery solution

Comment: @Jack, your fiddle does not fix the invalid HTML.

Comment: The OP is clearly new to web programming, i'm just giving him a point in the right direction. @bfaveretto thanks, i've updated the jsFiddle now. jQuery will solve many of the cross-browser compatability problems that he may face.

Comment: I love using jQuery and all that's true.  However, some would argue that loading the jQuery library is overkill when plain JavaScript would suffice just fine.

Comment: i am using google chrome , and javascript works good with it , but just this statement doesnt' work , i will try your answer

Comment: @WilliamKinaan, if you can't get [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10502096/594235), [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xxgdB/) or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2dUfa/) to work, then you probably won't understand jQuery any better.  (your problem is not the JavaScript).

Comment: maybe you are right , i doen't knw jquery , but i am using javascriopt will and it was works :( , sorry man i wasted your time , i will keep trying

Comment: @WilliamKinaan, Just pick the answer with the most up-votes and apply it to your code **exactly** as explained.  If it doesn't work, then provide a link to  your page, a demo, or create a jsFiddle of your own.  Simply saying _"still doesn't work"_ is not helping anyone.

Comment: it woooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooorks :) :) :) thank you ,really

Answer (score 5):

The `<li>` tag must be inside an `<ul>` or `<ol>`, and the only allowed children for `<ul>` and `<ol>` are `<li>` tags. This means your `<input>` should be outside the `<ul>`:

```
<input type="button" onclick="appear()"/>
<ul>
    <li id="addQuestionChoices">roma</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yes : not = i know , but i wrote it quickly , and i am using ul , but i put there just a shot code , maybe someone help me, thank you for answering , and do u have the solution?

Comment: Okay, answer updated after you posted more code. The invalid HTML may be causing the li to not be inserted into the DOM at all. Your js code is fine.

Comment: yes for sure /ul , but i told u , i just put here a simple code of my problem, the code is very large so i just put where is the wrong

Comment: @WilliamKinaan yes, you can't have anything but `<li>` tags as immediate children of an `<ul>`. If fixing that doesn't work, please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 2):

just be sure to define the function **before**, like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2dUfa/

```
<script>
function appear() {
    document.getElementById('addQuestionChoices').style.display= "block";
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="appear()" value="appear" />

<ul>
   <li id="addQuestionChoices">roma</li>
</ul>
```

As a sidenote: the default display property of a `<li>` element is `list-item` (and not `block`)

Comment: Yes, this was my thought too.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `<li>` inside of a `<ol>` or `<ul>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using inline Javascript code, and instead focus on keeping it separated.  Attach your event handler to the object in a script tag (or, better yet, a script file loaded at the end of the document), something like this:

```
<input id="clickButton" type="button" value="submit" />
    <ul>
        <li id="addQuestionChoices">roma</li>
    </ul>

<script>
    document.getElementById('clickButton').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('addQuestionChoices').style.display="block"
    };
</script>
```

You can see a working example of this at http://jsfiddle.net/xxgdB/

Note also you can use either `list-item` or `inherit` in the display field to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Then there's something deeper going on, because this is a working example (see the JSFiddle link).

Comment: @WilliamKinaan, what are you talking about?  This is a live [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xxgdB/) of this solution.  Please provide more than _"doesn't work"_ if you want to get to the root of your problem.

Comment: ok sorry man , i tried as u give me but still the same problem , sorry