# jQuery isn't working between <li></li>

Tags: jquery, zclip

I wrote a simple script that copies text to clipboard using zClip library http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/.

```
<ul>
 <!-- Iterates trough a list of items -->
  <li>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function($){
            $('#cpbtn${id}').zclip({
                path:'resources/zclip/ZeroClipboard.swf',
                copy:function(){return $('#cptext${id}').val();}
            });
        });
    </script>

    <input type="hidden" value="userfiles/images/${imageName}" id="cptext${id}"/>
    <a class="btn btn-primary cpbtn" id="cpbtn${id}">Copy URL</a>

  </li>
 <!-- End of iterator -->
</ul>
```

But it isn't working between `<ul><li></li></ul>` tags, if I remove the `<ul><li></li></ul>`, it's working. I put it between tags cause it iterates trough a list of items, I tried to put the zClip method out of `<ul><li></li></ul>` but I don't know how to trigger `.zclip();` method. What is wrong? Where I messed up?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502067/javascript-doesnt-work-with-li-tag . There is a jquery solution in jsfiddle. - http://jsfiddle.net/SvufY/1/

Comment: Sorry, but it's not about how to add more `<li></li>`, it's about zClip, and how to trigger it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with position of zClip generated element.

I've put `<a class="btn btn-primary cpbtn" id="cpbtn${id}">Copy URL</a>` in a `<div style="position: relative;"></div>` and it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('ul li').find('a').each(function() {
    // cache jquery var
    var current = $(this);

    current.zclip({
        path: 'resources/zclip/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: function() {
            return current.prev().val();
        }
    });
});​
```

Put this zClip method out of `<ul><li></li></ul>` and call it once only.

Comment: I did this, but it isn't getting into method zclip();, only in foreach, I suppose the .zclip() is triggered only on click of something, button, link, or something else, but not a simple call to it